# ¿Cómo definir min y un max de un input date en angular usando variables?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un input de tipo date, al cual le tengo que definir que su max es el día actual, y el min un año antes. Para hacer esto realizo lo siguiente.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="ultima-fecha-compra" name="ultima-fecha-compra" [min]="anoAntes" [max]="hoy">
```

En el html pongo los atributos con `[]` para poder utilizar una variable de mi typescript.

En el typescript defino esas variables en el `ngOnInit`.

```
export class xComponent implements OnInit {

  fecha = new Date();
  hoy = '';
  anoAntes = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Obtener fecha de hoy y de una año antes
    this.hoy = `${this.fecha.getFullYear()}-${this.fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${this.fecha.getDate()}`;
    this.anoAntes = `${this.fecha.getFullYear() - 1}-${this.fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${this.fecha.getDate()}`;
  }

}
```

También intenté con:

```
export class xComponent implements OnInit {

  fecha : Date;
  hoy = '';
  anoAntes = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Obtener fecha de hoy y de una año antes
    this.fecha = new Date();
    this.hoy = `${this.fecha.getFullYear()}-${this.fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${this.fecha.getDate()}`;
    this.anoAntes = `${this.fecha.getFullYear() - 1}-${this.fecha.getMonth() + 1}-${this.fecha.getDate()}`;
  }

}
```

¿Hay otra manera de lograr esto o podrían ayudarme con este error?

Answer (score 0):

Mi error fue no saber que los atributos max y min no reciben números como `1, 2, 3, 4...9`. Necesitan valores como `01, 02, 03,...,09`.

Lo resolví pasando los datos del mes y del día a esta función.

```
limpiarNumero( n: number ) {
  return n < 10 ? `0${n}` : n.toString();
}

limpiarNumero(1); // 01
limpiarNumero(10); // 10
```